# Can I handle more than 1280 bytes per tx?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Validating Signatures On Chain, and length of signer can be upto 100, but for now let's say it is 50, so 50 signature will be there `50*32 + 20*50 = 2600 bytes` and also there will be some other data as params to function and accounts which takes some space, and i just can't able to create multiple tx as it is atomic tx, is it possible to make this happen or do i have to think of some other approach?
Please correct if I am wrong!!

Edit:
I have to verify an EdDSA signature on a given message hash on a chain signed by multiple user sets, and the list of signatures can be up to 200. Each signature needs to be passed to the function via an argument, but the limit is only 1024 bytes. Since each signature will be 64 bytes, that means 64 * 200 = 12800 bytes, which exceeds the limit. Is there another approach possible for achieving the same?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: As it's currently worded, it's hard to understand your question. A Solana transaction only allows 1232 bytes maximum at the moment.

Comment: Hello Jon, I have to verify an EdDSA signature on a given message hash on a chain signed by multiple user sets, and the list of signatures can be up to 200. Each signature needs to be passed to the function via an argument, but the limit is only 1024 bytes. Since each signature will be 64 bytes, that means 64 * 200 = 12800 bytes, which exceeds the limit. Is there another approach possible for achieving the same?
Is it clear now?

Comment: Much clearer, thanks! Be sure to update your question too

Answer (score 1):

Since a Solana transaction only allows for 1232 bytes of instruction data, you'll need to send the signatures in batches, and "tick off" when a particular user has signed using on-chain state. Maybe you have an account like:

```
struct Signatures {
    has_signed: Vec<(Pubkey, bool)>
}
```

Whenever you receive a valid signature for a pubkey, you mark that the have signed by flipping the bool.

You could use the Anchor Multisig example program to see how to achieve something to that effect https://github.com/coral-xyz/multisig